# python - can't get audio player working

Tags: python, python-3.x

everything works except the next song doesn't play after the first is finished.

```
import os, random
from pygame import mixer
from pynput import keyboard
startup = 0
pause = 0
volume = 0.5
def Picker():
    global startup
    global volume
    startup += 1
    if startup > 1:
        ThisSong = random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\...\\Music"))
        NextSong = random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\...\\Music"))
        ThisSong = NextSong
        if ThisSong != NextSong:
            mixer.init()
            mixer.music.load("C:\\Users\\...\\Music" + ThisSong)
            mixer.music.play(0)
            mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
            while mixer.music.get_busy():
                def on_press(key):
                    global pause
                    global volume
                    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='-'):
                        volume -= 0.1
                        if volume < 0.1:
                            volume = 0.1
                        mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
                    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='='):
                        volume += 0.1
                        if volume > 1:
                            volume = 1
                        mixer.music.set_volume(volume)
                    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='['):
                        pause += 1
                        if pause == 1:
                            mixer.music.pause()
                            pause = 2
                        if pause == 3:
                            mixer.music.unpause()
                            pause = 0
                with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener: listener.join()
            else:
                Picker()
        else:
            pass
Picker()
Picker()
```

[screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Tqz.png)

I can't get it to work, i'm very new to python so i'm probably missing something
obvious

Comment: Please post your code as code in the question, not as an offsite link to a scaled-down screenshot.

Comment: Please read this:  [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting: Thx @JGreenwell for copying the code.

Ok, so first, I’ll help you clean your code.

#### Things that are wrong

1. Having all that ThisSong and NextSong things: It won’t get saved when you *restart* `Picker()`. Either just have ThisSong, or place the ThisSong and NextSong assignment with the volume and pause variables:

.

```
pause = 0 # this is a problem! Next point
volume = 0.5
ThisSong = random.choice(...)
NextSong = random.choice(...)
```

---

2. The pause variable should be a boolean (`True`/`False`) and the pausing code should be like this:

.

```
pause = not pause
if pause:
    # pause
else:
    # unpause
```

Also, it would ideally be called `paused`

---

3. `on_press` and the Listener declaration should be outside the while loop, because otherwise they just keep being declared every time it loops. Then you should `import time` and put `time.sleep(500)` or something like that in the while loop, so that it doesn’t check every fraction of second.

---

As for the next song not playing, I don’t really know, but I’d suggest entering `Picker()` in the shell after the program has run (`python -i script.py` from CMD, IDLE leaves you in a shell by default). I would also suggest really following recommendation #3 as having them in the loop may break the loop and stop it from finishing. Most importantly, I would ask you to debug your code by adding print in every step of your code:

```
print(1)
if something:
     print(2)
etc...
```

And seeing where it blocks

P.S.: The random dots are because you can’t have code in lists, so I had to exit the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! also, thanks JGreenwell for writing my code out, it wasn't working for me last night which is why i posted the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Working solution, incase anyone else has the same problem as me in the future :)

```
from pygame import mixer
from pynput import keyboard
import threading
import random
import os

paused = 0

def player():
    song = random.choice(os.listdir("C:\\users\\...\\desktop\\music"))
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load("C:\\users\\...\\desktop\\music\\" + song)
    mixer.music.play(0)
    while mixer.music.get_busy():
        pass
    else:
        player()

def main():
    t = threading.Thread(target = player, name = 'thread1', args = ())
    t.start()

main()

def on_press(key):
    global paused
    if key == keyboard.KeyCode(char='['):
                paused = not paused
                if paused:
                    mixer.music.pause()
                else:
                    mixer.music.unpause()
with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener: listener.join()
```